# Auto-Backup via FTP service

Tags: backup, remote, online-storage

I'm wondering if there is any online service which keeps incremental backups from a server incrementally.

I'm looking at Mozy etc. but I'm not sure if they offer this service.

I basically need a backup service for RackSpace Cloud sites. I do not want to use PHP etc. to push the backups. I would like the service to auto-pull files etc. Something like subscribe and forget in terms of service.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit out of date but see the links at http://pushsite.sourceforge.net/readme.html#if (NB pushsite itself is intended to run on the files to be copied - not the mirror, but if you feel like doing some Perl programming it would not need a lot of changes).

Project Gutenberg [recommend](http://pge.rastko.net/howto/mirror-howto) (amongst others) [mirror](http://search.cpan.org/~fleitner/Mirror-1.0/mirror) for maintaining a replica of their content.